# Relativity in regard to space combat

Tags: space-travel, relativity, combat

How would relativity affect space combat? I'm wondering how it would work at all. If everyone is moving at different speeds, then they're experiencing time differently, and maybe seeing ships where there are none anymore... Or yet. (Maybe not that last two words, but you see my point)

Preferably to dogfight type space combat, but if there is a more effective, realistic way, then please, do tell me, and answer the question as it applies there.

Comment: This may be a bit broad.  There is a remarkable degree of disparity when it comes to space combat.  We see everything from the dogfights of Star Wars: episode I to systems where combat consists of "warping in" at 0.9c, dropping a few kinetic warheads, and warping out.  Do you have a flavor of space combat you would like to focus on?

Comment: @CortAmmon edited question

Answer (score 3):

## It Is and Is Not Complicated

Some of your intuition for low-speed combat translates into high-speed combat. Ships have maximum maneuverability, so after a given time they can be in one of a few places. The principles of hitting things would still hold:

1. You determine their velocity (direction + speed)
2. Knowing your weapons speed, you send your projectile to intercept with them
3. Repeat until target is down.

Aiming your weapons would likely be automated, as most people do not have inborn intuitions about how relativity changes things. There is also the issue of gravity wells and warping, but a good targeting program will fix that. This may result in people hitting a "shoot them" button, not bothering with aiming. (Unless your fighters want to use [the force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gr8nnnMjVA).)

People/ships traveling at high speed would [have "slower" clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity#Special_relativity), so their reaction time to projectiles would need to increase. Your reaction times from when you perceive an object coming at you and when you can implement the correction to your course is greatly reduced when you're moving fast. This may result in ships purposefully engaging in erratic courses, simply to avoid / throw off the enemy and because they simply cannot *detect and avoid* projectiles before those projectiles strike.

Given the vastness of space, though, it could all come down to detecting the other person first. For instance, if you see an enemy ship appear on the far side of a star because of [gravitational lensing,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Light_deflection_and_gravitational_time_delay) your targeting program needs to take this into account. This may result in your gun shooting at (what appears to be) really blank space, no where near the target.

You would also really need to know how fast the other person's ship and projectiles are. Ideally, you would also want to know where they are heading as well. If we detect some craft going at 0.6c, and our maximum weapon speed is .5c, we cannot always hit them. Even if we do attempt to hit them, their course may have deviated so much that our weapon misses them entirely when it reaches "where they ought to be."

Comment: Note that a fast-moving target will see *your* clock as moving slower.  This seems paradoxical, as it looks like they simultaneously have more and less time to react... of course, they see the projectile moving at them faster, so the amount of reaction time is the same in both frames.  As to whether you end up having more or less due to relativistic effects, I'll have to think about that some more.

Comment: @2012rcampion That's a complicated part. In any case, the faster a projectile moves towards you, the less time you have to react... Which carries over from non-relativistic fights.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no good answer to this. Orbital warfare will be much different than in interplanetary space. And both depend on the type of power sources and engines that are available. Probably the most realistic battles would be drone-to-drone. My guess is that both sides would lose, iow there'd be no winners. It is true that if you can somehow stay invisible, that your side would win, but the difficulty in hiding waste heat seems insurmountable on time scales of more than seconds or minutes. If your question is about interstellar FTL scenarioes (or ones where momentum or gravity can be increased or eliminated instantly), any kind of magic you want to add that your fans accept as being credible is good enough. By definition, there's nothing IN space to fight about, so the exact strategic goals would need to be made specific. Any spaceship capable of typical sci-fi inteplanetary travel (here, there, and back again) could extort a world by threatening to throw rocks down at its major cities. There isn't any ground-based response to this would - any attack which would give the spaceship plenty of time to strike and flee (assuming there was someplace to go). The only defense would be a vast shell of satellites (or possibly multiple shells) armed with laser weapons. The expense would be stupendous. Basically, planets are effectively defenseless against enemy attack. Mutual Assured Destruction would be the only effective defense. I should also mention that combat in orbit around a planet is likely to leave the planet blanketed with so much shrapnel that future launches would be very difficult, if not impossible for decades if not centuries. Spaceships moving relative to each other at relativistic velocities are far beyond our capabilities, and the faster such a ship maneuvers, the greater the mass loss (and heat generated). In other words, most of the scenarios involving fraction-of-light-speed battles are impossible without some magic foo-foo dust (irrespective of any possible engine technology)...meaning the spaceship can't use more energy than you have in the spaceship, and most of that energy is E=mc², the energy of the mass of the ship (and its contents). But perhaps you can tap the energy of the vacuum, or some such magic foo-foo dust. You still have the problems that high accelerations will turn humans into jelly and roast us in the waste heat.